# PHP can't strip slashes when trying to echo mysql escaped data to XML using DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, stripslashes

I inserted in database some HTML text after escaping them using mysql_real_escape_string, and I am trying to add them to XML document to be read by flash file, I am using DOMDocument class to make the XML document, here's my tries and outputs:
try 1:

```
$descC = $doc->createCDATASection(stripslashes($sql['body']));
$desc = $doc->createElement('desc');
$desc->appendChild($descC);
```

output:

A lot of slashes !

try 2:

```
$desc = $doc->createElement('desc',htmlentities(stripslashes($sql['body'])));
```

output:

Also alot of slashes

Any ideas ?

Comment: Where exactly does `$sql['body']` come from? From the database? If yes, it shouldn't have any slashes

Comment: It comes from the database, It has slashes because I escaped it before inserting

Comment: @user1460518 — Escaping replaces characters with special meaning with escape sequences. It does not add slashes to the *data*.

Answer (score 0):

I think magic quotes are enabled in your configuration.

you must check it before escaping vai mysql_real_escape_string() as it will add more slashes.

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){

$b = stripslashes($b);

}

$b = mysql_real_escape_string($b);

Comment: The proper solution would be to turn off magic_quotes to begin with, rather than slapping on a bandaid.

Answer (score 0):

> It comes from the database, It has slashes because I escaped it before inserting

your data shouldn't have extraneous slashes when it comes out of the database; what is added when escaping the data shouldn't be visible in the final result, no `stripslashes()` should be necessary any more.

You most likely have a problem in the way you prepare your data for the database. Maybe show us that.